# why isn't picture showing up in card?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, image, card

I am trying to have the picture show up in the card component but whenever I try to import a picture into the imgSrc it doesn't appear in the card. If it helps the typing in BoxerData.tsx and Inside the card in Boxers.tsx as boxers are all string but I am not sure how to change it.

in BoxerCard.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { BoxerCardInterface } from "../data/Types";

export function BoxerCard({name,imgUrl,age,status,}:BoxerCardInterface) {
  return (
    <div className="card w-96 glass m-12">
    <figure><img src={imgUrl} alt="picture"/></figure>
    <div className="card-body">
      <h1 className="card-title flex-col">{name}</h1>
      <div className="card-actions justify-end">
      <button className="btn gap-2">age: {age} Years Old</button>     
      <button className="btn gap-2">{status}</button>     
   
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  );
};
```

in BoxerCardInterface.tsx

```
import React from "react";

export interface BoxerCardInterface {
  name: string;
  imgUrl: any;
  age: any;
  status: string;
}
```

in Boxers.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { BoxerCard } from "../components/BoxerCards";
import BoxerData from "../data/BoxerData";



export function Boxers() 
{
    return (
    <div className="flex flex-col md: flex-rows items-center justify-center">
        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-4">
            {BoxerData.map(boxers => (
                <BoxerCard
                imgUrl={boxers.imgUrl}
                name={boxers.name}
                age={boxers.age}
                status={boxers.status}
                />
            ))

            }
        </div>

    </div>
    )
}
```

in BoxerData.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { BoxerCardInterface } from "./Types";

export default [
    {
    name: 'Natalia Castaneda',
    imgUrl: 'src\pictures\natalia.jpg',
    age: '19',
    status: 'Open'
   }, 
   {
    name: 'Jocelyn Castaneda',
    imgUrl: '',
    age: '12 ',
    status: 'Novice'
   }, 
   {
    name: 'Joel Sanchez',
    imgUrl: '',
    age: '19',
    status: 'Open'
   }, 
   {
    name: 'Scott Mcfadden',
    imgUrl: '',
    age: '20 ',
    status: 'Open'
   }, 
   {
    name: 'Augusta Grace',
    imgUrl: '',
    age: '26 ',
    status: 'Novice'
   },
   {
    name: 'Mia Andre',
    imgUrl: '',
    age: '13',
    status: 'Novice'
   },
];
```

[image: problem]

Comment: What exact `src` was generated in the DOM? Check it in chrome dev tools.

Comment: Can you inspect the element and check if sourceURL matches ?

Comment: thank you, it seemed like the relative path being copied and pasted didn't output the right path.